# How can I exclude archived messages from the multiple inboxes view?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-archive

I turned off conversation mode.
I set up a filter that applies the label Family to any email coming from a family member's email address.
I set up a separate mailbox inside Gmail for any emails with the label Family.

Is there a way to set up the search filter to not show me the ones I have archived? I have tried the following:

```
label:Family AND -in:inbox
label:Family AND NOT in:inbox
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You've got it a bit backwards there. "Archive" simply means to remove the "Inbox" label. So, if something is "unarchived", it means it's still in your Inbox.

```
label:Family in:inbox
```

Just a note: `AND` is superfluous, because the search is implicitly "AND". Also, "NOT" does not work. `-` is used for negation.

Comment: Talk about me making it harder than it has to be! I got so twisted, I missed the obvious. Thank you!